# Rstudio Launch & Run Code Automation Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to automate the Launch of RStudio and Running the Code using Powershell so the end user does not have to deal with RStudio and just get the end results of the code.

I have tried to Launch the RStudio application and that was successful.

I am not able to find any other helpful resources.

I tried looking at documentation to figure out if I can mimic the `Ctrl+Alt+R` which runs the whole script.

```
$OpenR = "V:\Corp\ro\965090\pub-db\Retail Erosion Analytics\Sam Khaled - Folder\Profit Check\Transaction Profit Check.R"

Start-Process -FilePath "$OpenR"
```

Launching RStudio but not able to figure out the Run code.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script using R command line, not RStudio?